# How to discard coefficients in the frequency domain without losing too much quality?

Tags: fft, python, frequency-domain, dct, scipy

I was reading a [text that shows that one can throw away 66% of the coefficients](http://www.csc.villanova.edu/~rschumey/csc4800/dct.html) and gets an image that is still acceptable.

I tried to [replicate it using python (last example)](https://github.com/leandromoreira/digital_video_introduction/blob/master/image_transform_frequency_domain.ipynb) and selectively throwing away some of the coefficients but I couldn't get a great image, mine is looking like a ghost.

**How can I discard that not so important to the image?**

[image: fft discarded coefficient example]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal

# loading the image
img = mpimg.imread('i/super_mario_head.png')

# image in frequency domain
fft_original = np.fft.rfft2(img)

# discarding some coefficients (except initial square 80x80)
for x in range(300):
    for y in range(300):
        discard_x = x > 80
        discard_y = y > 80

        if discard_x and discard_y:
            fft_original[x,y] = 0

# reverse from frequency to spatial
i_fft_original = np.fft.irfft2(fft_original)

f, (plt1, plt2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(15,15))

plt1.axis('off');plt1.set_title('Original');plt1.imshow(img[:,:,0], cmap='gray');
plt2.axis('off');plt2.set_title('Reversed');plt2.imshow(i_fft_original[:,:,0], cmap='gray');
```

Comment: Compare not real but absolute value of fft. Or just pick some radius in the fourier domain to throw away everything outside of that radius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are throwing away coefficients before checking to see if their current magnitudes are small (smaller than typically visible).

(You might also want to rescale what's left to preserve total energy.)

Comment: Thanks, do you know how can I check if its magnitudes are small? (ex: `fft_original[x,y] <= 0.01` ? )

Comment: "small" is relative to the psychology and physiology of human vision.  Test, or read published research for prior opinions.

Comment: Thanks, a lot :D I'll try `fft_original[x,y,0].real <= MIN`

Comment: I tried `fft_original[x,y,0].real < 20` but it caused also issues and then I tried a range query `> -2 and < 20` but it still weird.

Comment: The size of a "small" enough coefficient is likely not a constant, but varies greatly depending on the location in the 2D FFT and what's nearby in both the FFT and the image.

Comment: ;/ yeah, I first tried the approach of a square 80x80, from x = 0 and y = 0 and then I tried a triangle `x + y >= 80`.. :D but I'm gonna mix all your suggestions a the `threshold` outside of the triangle. Does it makes sense?

Comment: do you know how to rescale the fft array using numpy or scipy?

Answer (score 1):

Find largest value of fft_original and then Use a threshold which is 1/N times of it - say 1/10. Also compare with absolute value of each sample so that high magnitude negative values are preserved.

Comment: Thanks, is it the highest real value? or the imaginary part?

Comment: I tried with 1/10, `threshold = (1/10) * max_fft` and then compared using absolutes values `if abs(fft_original[x,y,0].real) <= threshold:` but it still looking ghostly.

Comment: I changed the color plane which I was working on (from 0 to 2) and then it looks more acceptable now.